# Is there a way to change the location of the tabs in a tabbed iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a way to change the location of the tabs in an tabbed iOS application? I'd like for the tabs to be on the top rather than the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITabBar` is intended to be used at the bottom.  That's what users expect.  There are good reasons for this, such as being able to change tabs with your thumb.

Even if you have a great reason why your application should behave differently from all the others, repositioning a `UITabBar` to the top will just look and feel wrong to users, who will know that *that* should not be *there*. Best to implement your own in that case, and make it quite clearly NOT a `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the standard Apple `UITabBar`, **No**. You can however make your own custom tab bar style control using a `UISegmentedControl`.

Try this example found on another website: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35054-display-tab-bar-items-top-screen.html#post149060

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the standard Apple UITabbar no. And this is for a reason because moving them to the top goes agains HIG and the standard interface.

If you require something at the top you should look at a UIToolBar but consider what you're doing before simple putting your most valuable app buttons at the top when users expect them at the bottom.